# Regex to find last two places in a group of numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have numbers with the following form:

```
02R-01240-250A
02R-01242-250
15-09110-200X
15-09110-212
```

I can capture the middle 5 digits (always 5) with:

```
([^-]+[0-9]{4})
```

but I really want to grab the last two digits of this 5 number set and make a new column in my Pandas dataframe. I also need be able to grab the middle for a new column as well.

Comment: If you posted the code, it would be easier and quicker to provide the answer. Please do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these patterns:

```
-[0-9]{2}[0-9]([0-9]{2})- #last two digits
-[0-9]{2}([0-9])[0-9]{2}- #middle digit
```

Based on your need to extract two things, you could use two capture groups with `re.search()` to get the last two digits and middle digit at once. This requires that there are always five numbers, but you say that there always are.

```
s = re.search("-[0-9]{2}([0-9])([0-9]{2})-", your_string)
oneColumn = s.group(1) #middle digit
anotherColumn = s.group(2) #last two digits
```

The parentheses in the pattern enclose the two different capture groups.

Comment: Kamses..I was able to make your solution work in my code and the regex's return the items I'm seeking. Thanks. I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the pattern remains the same, try out a non-`regex` solution:

```
s = '02R-01240-250A'

print(s.split('-')[1][-2:])
# 40
```

Comment: Nice use of slicing.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
-[0-9]*([0-9]{2})-
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QqkMul/1). The captured digits will be the last two before the hyphen. To grab the digit before the last two, use

```
-[0-9]*([0-9])[0-9]{2}-
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QqkMul/2).

**Details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `([0-9]{2})` - Capturing group 1 (when using `extract`, that is the value returned by the method): two digits that are followed with...
- `-` - a hyphen.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I can see the result in the demo but I'm not able to duplicate your result in Regex Buddy using the python 3.6 flavor (I tried 2.7 as well). Not sure why. How would the regex change to grab the middle digit only?

Comment: Have you tested it in your python script? That should work for the last two digits.

Comment: @Kevin If you posted the code, I would be able to provide a direct solution.